# Variable Not Defined Error

Tags: python

I'm getting an error saying sum1 is not defined

```
def zodiacMatch(sum1, sum2):
    sum1 = input("please enter your zodiac number")
    sum2 = input("please enter your other number")
    if sum1 + sum2 <= 7:
        print "low compatibility"

#MAIN#
zodiacMatch(sum1, sum2):
sum1 = input("please enter your zodiac number")
sum2 = input("please enter your other number")
```

Comment: you neeed to parse it to int and then calculate the sum

Comment: I think `input` should handle that by itself. At least python 2.7 does it.

Comment: @PauloBu: In Python 3.x, `input` is the same as 2.x's `raw_input`, so it doesn't handle that by itself.

Comment: The problem here is that you're calling the function with `sum1` and `sum2` _before_ you've gotten the values for those variables. You have to do it the other way around.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to input the values and pass them into `zodiacMatch`, just for it to ignore the values you gave it and input new ones again. Just do one or the other, not both.

Comment: Yes, I've heard about that, he doesn't specify so I will in my answer just in case. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: The following chunk of code uses a for loop to calculate factorial of a number. 

0 factorial = 1, 1 factorial = 1, 2 factorial = 2*1, 3 factorial = 3*2*1 etc.

Change the code so it uses a while loop instead of a for loop.

Comment: @user2457341 first of all, if you want to ask another question, dont do it in comment. Make a whole other question. Second, we're not going to write the code for you. You need to give it a go first

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (if you're in Python version lower than 3.x. `python --version` to check)

```
def zodiacMatch(sum1, sum2):
    if sum1 + sum2 <= 7:
        print "low compatibility"

#MAIN#
sum1 = input("please enter your zodiac number")
sum2 = input("please enter your other number")
zodiacMatch(sum1, sum2):
```

I hope this will have good karma :D

Comment: yeaaaaahhhhhh!!!!!!! thank you so much

Comment: This site doesn't have karma points, it has rep points. But you've already got 20 of those, and will probably get more (because this is a perfect answer), so… good enough, right? :)

Comment: Lol, I say about karma because the code was about zodiac signs (maybe they aren't even related but it was a bad joke :) )

Comment: i have 2 more questions that need to be solved

Comment: @user2457341 go for it, there are a lot of users in this community willing to help you. But try to do something first about them and when you can't find the answer, ask the questions here :) Also you can accept the answers that worked for you.

Comment: The following chunk of code uses a for loop to calculate factorial of a number. 

0 factorial = 1, 1 factorial = 1, 2 factorial = 2*1, 3 factorial = 3*2*1 etc.

Change the code so it uses a while loop instead of a for loop.

Comment: @user2457341 this is not the place to post the question, you should ask another question.

Comment: Same way you post this question. There is a button above that says "Ask Answer". Click it :D